# can't import pyqtgraph on 32 bit win 10

Tags: python, import, windows-10, 32-bit, pyqtgraph

I can't manage to import pyqtgraph in 32 bit win 10 installations.(I need it to run on 32 bit windows)

There is a problem with win 10 related to pyqtgraph Although It works when os is 64 bit only and python is 32 bit and other libs as PyQy5 and pyqtgraphs are 32 bit as well

Even after I run python on the cli and enter the command as follows:

**import pyqtgraph as pg**

I can't get a response meaning there is not ant any error but the cli keeps running a while and it exits the python cli finally

[Here is the result of import in 32bit win10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMkI2.png)

[Here is what I expect as tested in 64 bit win10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWzkV.png)

It should import the framework(pyqtgraph) like the other 32 bit libs in the requirements.txt

No import at all even when running python on the cli and run import pyqtgraph

Tested environment(s)

PyQtGraph version: 0.13.2 but not with this command , instead pip list shows the version only

Qt Python binding: 5.15.9 but not with this command , again from pip list

Python version: Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr 5 2023, 00:20:04) [MSC v.2019 32 bit (Intrel)] on win32

NumPy version: 1.24.1 but not with this command , again from pip list
Operating system:

32 bit win 10 Home(32 bit os , x64 based processor).

Installation method: pip

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It isn't clear what is your problem.  What happens when you run ```import pyqtgraph as pg```?  If it doesn't error, then there isn't a problem.   It isn't clear what it is you are having issues with.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the links for the error case and success case.My program doesnt show up when I run it with python main.py in the cli as it can not import the pyqtgraph library.But there is no need to share the code I think because even I can not import in this python cli interface and it explains everything